# How to execute .m files in Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

How do I execute `.m` files in Octave?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open .m files in octave on OSX 10.6.8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998630/how-to-open-m-files-in-octave-on-osx-10-6-8)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In the Octave prompt, simply type `file1`.

Of course, you need to make sure Octave can recognize its path.

Answer (score 20):

In octave prompt, type `run("file1.m")` or entering the filename without `.m` extension.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to execute a file in Octave ::

1. Simply type the filename without extension  .
2. Type run("filename.m") in the command line of Octave .

   Then press ctrl + c to exit the file in middle of the run .

Example ::

[image: File name here is 'ex1' which is being executed]

Answer (score 3):

To run your Octave file in GNU Octave.

1. navigate to editor tab at the bottom of command editor
2. Press Ctrl+O or Go to file and open your file
3. Pres F5 or Navigate to Run and Save and Run

You can see the logs in command window

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check that your file name is same as the function name.